# Move object by a given distance on rotation of another (bolt & screw)

Tags: constraints

I am looking to make a constraint to animate a cnc model. So i want to have a given object travel along an axis as a result of the rotation of another screw and bolt.

To be specific a 360 degree rotation should move the child object 2mm limiting the rotations to 125 or 45 000 degrees for a total travel distance of 250mm.

Constraint should be able to work in both directions like a normal bolt and screw animation.

Thanks

Comment: I am not optimistic that you will be able to make it "work in both directions".  My first instinct matches Craig's: that you should use a driver.  But then the target of the driver is the master and the object with the driver is the slave..

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to set up a custom driver based on the rotation of the screw. This video is on corrective shape keys but is a good introduction to the use of drivers in animation 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6mrceZ6fe-o

Answer (score -2):

[Humane Rigging](https://store.blender.org/product/humane-rigging/) by Nathan Vegdahl may be your best bet for a truly deep understanding of rigs and constraints. It's also available on Youtube if you're strapped for cash, but you won't have the benefit of the tutorial rigs he provides.